# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning TypeError when deploying multiple contracts (>200) at the same time

Tags: javascript, nodejs, receipts, express

I get the following error:

```
(node:6540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.removeListener is not a function
    at Object.receipt (c:\Users\pruto\OneDrive\Documents\Smart contracts\xInvest-Backend-1.3\node_modules\@truffle\contract\lib\handlers.js:135:10)
    at Function.start (c:\Users\pruto\OneDrive\Documents\Smart contracts\xInvest-Backend-1.3\node_modules\@truffle\contract\lib\override.js:54:24)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:58:5)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:501:9)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
(node:6540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 561)
```

It happens when I am processing a large number of records posted via express. The contracts get deployed anyway but I would like to know why this error appears and if there is way of preventing it. Here is the relevant node.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));

// Enable all CORS requests 
app.use(cors());

// enable middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.json());

const Web3 = require("web3");
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

require('dotenv').config();
const provider = new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.INFURA_URL);

var contract    = require("@truffle/contract");

const insurerArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Insurer.json');
var insurerContract = contract(insurerArtifacts);
insurerContract.setProvider(provider);

const platformArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Platform.json');
var platformContract = contract(platformArtifacts);
platformContract.setProvider(provider);

const portfolioArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Portfolio.json');
var portfolioContract = contract(portfolioArtifacts);
portfolioContract.setProvider(provider);

const vendorArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Vendor.json');
var vendorContract = contract(vendorArtifacts);
vendorContract.setProvider(provider);

const clientArtifacts = require('./build/contracts/Client.json');
var clientContract = contract(clientArtifacts);
clientContract.setProvider(provider);

function convertStringX(myString, len)
    {
    console.log("my String = " + myString);
    var myBuffer = [];
    var temp = Buffer.from(myString);

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
        // eliminate empty characters (different than spaces which are 0x20)
        if (i < myString.length)
            myBuffer.push(temp[i]);
        else
            myBuffer.push(0x0);         
        } 

    console.log(myBuffer);
    return myBuffer;
    }

var myPlatform;
const platformAddress = '0x...';

async function instantiatePlatform(deployedAddress) {
    myPlatform = await platformContract.at(deployedAddress);
    console.log("myPlatform address " + myPlatform.address);
    }

//myPlatform =  myPlatformContract.at(contractAddress);
instantiatePlatform(platformAddress);

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.connection.setTimeout(0); // this could take a while

    next();
});

var whitelist = ['localhost:8080']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
    var corsOptions;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
        corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
    } else {
        corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

var countClientTxs = 1;
var countClientReceipts = 1;

async function createClient(_ClientUIC, _ClientName, _ClientGroup, _ClientNACE, _insurerAddress, 
    _CreditLine, _CreditLineDate, _ClientCurrency, _ClientCity, _ClientCountry)
    {
    myPlatform.createClient(_ClientUIC, _ClientName, _ClientGroup, 
        _ClientNACE, _insurerAddress, _CreditLine, _CreditLineDate, _ClientCurrency, _ClientCity, _ClientCountry,
        { from:provider.getAddress() })
        .once('transactionHash', function(hash) {
            console.log("TxHash " + countClientTxs.toString() + ": " + hash);
            countClientTxs++;
        }).on('receipt', function(receipt) { 
            console.log("receipt " + countClientReceipts.toString() + ": " + JSON.stringify(receipt)); 
            countClientReceipts++;
        }).then(function(result) {
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    } // async function createClient(_ClientUIC, _ClientName, _ClientGroup, _ClientNACE, _insurerAddress, _CreditLine, _CreditLineDate, _ClientCurrency, _ClientCity, _ClientCountry)


app.post('/deploy_client', (req, res) => {

    var insurerAddress = '0x...';

    var myInput=req.body;
    console.log("myInput "+ myInput.length+ " " +myInput[0].clientUIC);

    for (i=0;i<myInput.length;i++)
        {
        // Only add record if invoice is non-empty
        if (myInput[i].clientUIC != null && myInput[i].clientUIC != "")
            {
            var myClientUIC = myInput[i].clientUIC;
            myClientUIC = convertStringX(myClientUIC, 16);
            console.log("myClientUIC "+ myClientUIC);
            var myClientName = myInput[i].clientName;
            myClientName = convertStringX(myClientName, 16);
            console.log("myClientName "+ myClientName);
            var myClientGroup = myInput[i].clientGroup;
            myClientGroup = convertStringX(myClientGroup, 16);
            console.log("myClientGroup "+ myClientGroup);
            var myClientNACE = myInput[i].clientNACE;
            myClientNACE = convertStringX(myClientNACE, 3);
            console.log("myClientNACE "+ myClientNACE); 
            var myCreditLine = myInput[i].creditLine;
            console.log("myCreditLine "+ myCreditLine);
            var myCreditLineDate = myInput[i].creditLineDate;
            console.log("myCreditLineDate "+ myCreditLineDate);
            var myClientCurrency = myInput[i].clientCurrency;
            myClientCurrency = convertStringX(myClientCurrency, 3);
            console.log("myClientCurrency "+ myClientCurrency);
            var myClientCity = myInput[i].clientCity;
            myClientCity = convertStringX(myClientCity, 32);
            console.log("myClientCity "+ myClientCity);
            var myClientCountry = myInput[i].clientCountry;
            myClientCountry = convertStringX(myClientCountry, 3);
            console.log("myClientCountry "+ myClientCountry);
            console.log("insurerAddress "+ insurerAddress);

            console.log("instance address " + myPlatform.address);

            createClient(myClientUIC, myClientName, myClientGroup, myClientNACE, insurerAddress, myCreditLine, 
                myCreditLineDate, myClientCurrency, myClientCity, myClientCountry);
            }
        }

        res.send("Data received!");

    }); // app.post('/deploy_client', (req, res) => {
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? Is it some kind of timeout happening?

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you create a promise inside a loop and you send the reply before they are confirmed. From the call stack something inside truffle is causing the error, it seems an object wasn't created properly or it is used after deletion.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks for your reply. I do not quite understand what you mean. Is something regarding the use of .on, .once and .then? There are 2 different types of issues - first, if I send 250 clients to be deployed, they are all deployed but I get the error you see. If I send 500, I get the error and maybe 300 will be deployed, the rest not. It is very strange behaviour. I have looked of course at the JSON being sent and it is fine. There is enough ether to pay for gas. Do I need to get a receipt at all? Sorry for my potentially "dumb" questions but I am really confused...

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Truffle https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2512.